# Bootstrap 4 accordion with collapsed button blinks before reaching end of expansion

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement an accordion. I based on this component ([go to fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dvlopherfromspace/yhuwt2wu/5/)) using bootstrap 4. While I was unable to reproduce the bug I'm trying to fix on SO forum, on my page this component "blinks" just before reaching the end of course on expansion. It is a page on Moodle system and I do not have access to the server. I'm just an admin who can modify the frontend using those tecnologies. I suspect that it might be something related to conflicts on the stylesheets that are already on place with this specific page. Please check my code.

```css
.spacer {
   height: 1em;
}
#competence {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#competence td, #competence th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#competence tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#competence tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#competence th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
     <b>
      A table
     </b>
          </button>
         </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
    <div dir="ltr">
        <table id="competence">
            <colgroup>
                <col width="332">
                <col width="129">
                <col width="125">
            </colgroup>
            <tbody style="border-color:black;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <p dir="ltr">Some text</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Do anyone have any clue on that?

Comment: *"I was unable to reproduce the bug I'm trying to fix here"* -- me neither. Case closed.

Comment: Wait, what is really driving me crazy is the fact that it works everywhere but on my page.

Comment: So, start doing the usual debugging steps: removing things one by one. Tedious but effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had same issue with collapsable items, this is caused in my case by putting padding on the "collapsable" div for example
`<div class="collapse pb-3" id="collapseExample">`
I resolved removing "pb-3" class from there and putting pt-3 class in the below not collapsable div element.

Answer (score 0):

Collapsible div must be with class "**card**" and with **no padding**.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet"       
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="p-5">
    <button class="btn btn-primary clickable d-block" aria-controls="accordion" 
            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion">Click me!</button>
    <div class="card m-0 collapse" id="accordion" 
         style="background-color:#d7dde3;border-radius:0">
      <p class="pl-2">Line 1</p>
      <p class="pl-2">Line 2</p>
      <p class="pl-2">Line 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```